# alert errors from console

Tags: javascript, error-handling, spreadsheet

I'm using a [tabletop js](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) to connect my javascript to spreadsheet.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fbLdxqdp/2/
I have this onclick button function to submit the url of my spreadsheet:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    // find closes textareau in this specific button DIV
    $(this).parent().find('textarea').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    
    var error_msg = console.error(message); 
    alert(error_msg)
});
```

If I enter the URL correctly, then I can work on the spreadsheet w/o any issues.

BUT if i have the wrong URL, i will get a console error.

How can I alert my self if I enter the wrong URL? Please see this screenshot for the error console: https://www.screencast.com/t/SAVKUn8V

the full javascript html: https://pastebin.com/DP6dkyxr

Comment: `console.error()` does not have a return value

Comment: um, `alert(message)` ?

Comment: Um, the error would be from the XHR request, has nothing to do with the code you provided.

Comment: @epascarello any ideas how can i get alerts if there's that console error?

Comment: Those errors are from the browser, doubt it is console error. Without knowing what the code is doing, there may or may not be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have assigning return value of `console.error` to `error_msg` there is no such a thing `console.error` don't return a value.

try as follows,

```
 alert(message)
```

Comment: alert(message) doesn't work.   $("button").click(function(){
   // find closes textareau in this specific button DIV
   $(this).parent().find('textarea').select();
   document.execCommand('copy');
   alert(message)
  });

Comment: you have to define message

Comment: $("button").click(function(){}) which button click you want track only one button in your jsfiddle UI